# Rendering another controllers action as a partial from another view in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to render a partial (e.g in controllerA) from another controller (e.g controllerB), in my view. The partial is rendering correctly with static content but when trying to access an instance variable, it fails. The instance variable is instantiated by an action in controllerB but this action is never called when simply rendering the partial.

Is there a way to call an action before rendering the partial?

Comment: share some code where you are getting error. may be your controller actions, views, partials.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you are rendering a template/partial, the instance variables it uses must be present. If the template/partial belongs to another action, it is responsibility of the action being executed to initialize all the instance variables the partial uses.

Generally it is not a very good idea for an action to execute other controller's actions directly. The proper way to direct the flow is by using `redirect_to`

```
redirect_to post_url(@post)
```

But, since your concern is a partial, just initialize all the necessary variables within the current action.

Answer (score 0):

Could you please try this one ?

```
render 'posts/show'
```

I'll render *show* action inside of *posts_controller*.